# What does "content-type" mean in headers of python requests library and if the value is text/html;charset=UTF-8?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I want to do some operations with response from python requests library. After I use below function;

```
response = requests.get(f'{AUTHORIZE_URL}?client_id={CLIENT_ID}&response_type=code&state={STATE}&redirect_uri={REDIRECT_URI}')
```

I need to get an URL something like this in return;

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/auth/?state=2b33fdd45jbevd6nam&code=MGY1MTMyNWY0YjQ0MzEwNmMxMjY2ZjcwMWE2MWY5ZDE5MzJlMjA1YjdkNWExNGRhYjIzOGI5NzQ5OWZkNTA5NA
```

While doing it, it will be easier to use JSON in order to get `state` and `code` values from URL but I cannot use it because I think the content type does not allow this.

Answer (score 1):

See this for Content-Type explanation: [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type)

In short the "content-type" in the headers of response got by using **requests.get** tells you what kind of the content server did send, in your case you'we got a response in the form of the HTML (like .html document) and you can read that response with **response.text**, if the "content-type" is "application/json" then you can read it as JSON like this **response.json()**.

I see that you use some local server, your local server should send in headers "Content-Type": "application/json" and then you should be able to read JSON from response like this (you need to send JSON not hmtl or text from server):

```
targetURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/auth/?state=2b33fdd45jbevd6nam&code=MGY1MTMyNWY0YjQ0MzEwNmMxMjY2ZjcwMWE2MWY5ZDE5MzJlMjA1YjdkNWExNGRhYjIzOGI5NzQ5OWZkNTA5NA'
response.get(targetURL).json()
```

Comment: I cannot get this response : `http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/auth/?state=2b33fdd45jbevd6nam&code=MGY1MTMyNWY0YjQ0MzEwNmMxMjY2ZjcwMWE2MWY5ZDE5MzJlMjA1YjdkNWExNGRhYjIzOGI5NzQ5OWZkNTA5NA` which you assigned it manually in your code. My problem is to get it into that string but how can I do that?

Comment: @Hektor could you add some more code and explanation of what are you trying to achieve? I see that you do a GET request to the server and as response you get URL? or you need to do another GET request to the http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/auth/?state=2b33fdd45jbevd6nam&code=MGY1MTMyNWY0YjQ0MzEwNmMxMjY2ZjcwMWE2MWY5ZDE5MzJlMjA1YjdkNWExNGRhYjIzOGI5NzQ5OWZkNTA5NA and you want that response in the form of JSON?

Comment: in the beginning I do not have the `code`value. The server sends it to me. What I only have is `response`value which I indicated it in my question. I can only send it to the server. Then, I should have a response from the server which should contain both `state`which I generate in local and should get the same value from the server and `code`which the server creates for me in order to proceed to the other steps such as requesting access token and etc.